# Mounting NTFS Partition that all users can read but only root can write too?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, fstab

I have an NTFS partition I use to share data between Ubuntu and Windows on `/dev/sda5`.

I am wondering if there is a way to make it readable by user (on a single user computer) but only write-able by root.

Basically all I want is to be able to listen to the music files in my player, for example, but have them be unable to be altered or deleted without sudo-ing.

Is this possible through `fstab`?

My current `fstab` entry:

> /dev/sda5 /media/disk ntfs defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,noatime 0 0

I imagine it is some sort of `umask` command or change in uid or gid, but I can't figure it out so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda5 /media/disk ntfs-3g defaults,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,noatime
```